# calculate the cumulative total of a report's column in SQL server for representing it in a table visual in Power BI

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement of calculating the running total week-wise for one of my report .I am using SQL server.
As an example : 
If I am having the quantity 100 in week 48 then 
for week 49
 total quantity = quantity of week 49 + week 48
week 50
 total quantity = quantity of week 49 + week 48 + week 50 and so on..

I want to represent the SQL query in Power BI through table visual.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

**Code:**

```
SELECT a.NAME, 
       a.item_segments, 
       a.description, 
       a.quantity, 
       a.order_type_text, 
       a.due_date 
FROM   dbo.zz a 
UNION 
SELECT     a.NAME, 
           a.item_segments, 
           a.description, 
           0, 
           b.order_type_text, 
           Getdate() due_date 
FROM       dbo.xx a 
CROSS JOIN dbo.yy b)
```

Comment: please provide sample data and code you have tried so far

Comment: select
a.name,
a.item_segments,
a.description,
a.quantity,
a.order_type_text,
a.due_date
from dbo.zz a
union
select
a.name,
a.item_segments,
a.description,
0,
b.order_type_text,
getdate() due_date
from dbo.xx a cross join dbo.yy b)

Comment: How can i provide the sample data to you?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).